# How to UPDATE from a Select in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

A little personal project i'm doing, kinda new in sql.
Lets say i have a table with multiples columns, but i want to work with 2 for this request: CODE and VALUE

Basically, the codes are like this : 1_A, 1_B, 1_C, 2_A, 2_B, 2_C, 3_A, 3_B, 3_C, etc... They are already created.
What i want to do is replace the VALUE from the C codes with the A codes: 1_A -> 1_C, 2_A->2_C, and so on. Without touching the other colmuns
What i thougt so far is :

`update TABLE set Value = (select value from TABLE from CODE like '%A%') where CODE like '%C%'`

But how do make sure that the Value associated with the code X_A gets copied into X_C specifically ? Like, so 1_A gets copied into 1_C and not 2_C. Maybe it has to do with JOIN, but honestly i don't get how those work yet

Edit : it's on oracle

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Something like `UPDATE TABLE SET Code = REPLACE(Code, 'A', 'C') WHERE CODE LIKE '%A';`. But the syntax is going to be different for each RDBMS product (sql server, mysql, sqlite, postgres, oracle, etc)

Comment: I'm using Oracle. And wouldn't UPDATE TABLE SET Code = REPLACE(Code, 'A', 'C') WHERE CODE LIKE '%A'; get rid of the A code ? I would have 2 C codes then

Comment: If you want to **copy** values, you need to `insert`. `update` only changes your values in place, so they'd have to already exist.

Comment: Tried to clarify a bit. All the values are already there, i do want to replace the C value with a copy of the A value

Comment: It may be simpler to DELETE all the rows with code X_C, then INSERT copies of all X_A rows after replacing the "A" with a "C". Is there any particular reason to want to UPDATE, instead of this simpler (and possibly faster) DELETE + INSERT?

Comment: The problem only makes sense if CODE is primary key (or candidate key, meaning potentially primary key, even if it is not specifically designated as such). Is that the case? Then - does every X_A code have a corresponding X_C code, no exceptions? And the same in the other direction - does every X_C code have an X_A code, no exception?

Comment: There are other columns, that i don't want to touch. Yes, CODE is primary and there's always X_A, X_B and X_C for every X

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to copy all the `A` values to `C` values, you should use an `insert` statement, not an `update` statement. This can be with the insert-select construct:

```sql
INSERT INTO mytbale (value)
SELECT REPLACE(value, 'A', 'C')
FROM   mytable
WHERE  value LIKE '%A'
```

Comment: Completely misunderstood the question. The CODE column, not the VALUE column, contains values like 2_A and 2_C. The VALUE may be anything (a number, a string, a user comment etc.). The OP wants to overwrite the VALUE of CODE = 2_C with the VALUE of CODE = 2_A.